# Angular асинхронная загрузка

Tags: http, typescript, angular

господа, помогите пожалуйста вот этот метод переписать асинхронно, что бы возвращался объект Observable>, а не просто
ServiceResult.

```
public getAccount(login: string, password: string): ServiceResult<Account>
  {
    let token: string;
    let role: string;
    let code: number;

    this.http
      .post(this.url, new InputUser(login, password))
      .subscribe((data: any) => { token = data.access_token; role = data.username; }, (error) => { code = error.statusCode });

    var result = new ServiceResult<Account>();

    if (code == 200) {
      result.data = new Account(token, role);
    } else
    {
      result.isError = true;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Спасибо.

Comment: @overthesanity, в том примере нет примера с ovservable. Здесь больше какой-нибудь flatMap подошел бы

Answer (score 2):

```
return this.http.post(this.url, new InputUser(login, password));
```